# How to create custom auto generated id? And how do I find auto generated id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dealer sign up  and  once the dealer signs up , It takes him to a
 confirmation page where the dealer profile is shown  and can confirm it.
So when I accept the values from the dealer I insert the values into a temporary table with an **auto generated ID** (which is a string) and then display the Profile in another page.
My questions are:

1. How do you generate an ID automatically when the dealer clicks on submit (type `VARCHAR` Example. RBCE001). This ID will be the `dealer_ID(PK)`.
2. Once generated and added to the temporary table , How do I find the auto-generated ID and display the information?
3. I also have to insert the auto generated dealer id in various other tables. I cannot do so without knowing it.

P.S I cannot use `POST` variables or `SESSIONS` as the information provided by the dealer is used to get multiple values from the DB. And then displayed. I do not require hard codes, I just require the logic or direct me in the right direction .

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: there are ways of doing this with strings with `views`. but once you cozy up to plain ints you might appreciate the headaches that you avoid with such a `fix`

Comment: @DrewPierce But I have seen banks and e-commerce stores using the `VARCHAR` type for ID's . Even Logistics for that matter.

Comment: do you need help in doing this? i would gladly show you how. bet you can figure it out tho. if you need help, tell me whether or not it is  to be a Primary Key or just an ID. show a table create statement (dont hand type it, cut and paste it showing indexes etc), and include a 2nd table that references/uses the custom id we are talking about such as `RBCE001`.